# Fast way to fill array with Objects

Tags: javascript, loops, three.js

I have to fill an array with a lot of objects. My current Implementation is this:

```
let useVertices = [];
const len = this.indices.length;
for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
    let index = this.indices[i]*3;
    useVertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(
        this.vertices[index],
        this.vertices[index+1], 
        this.vertices[index+2])
    );
}
```

`this.indices` is an Int32Array with a length of almost 4 million.
`this.vertices`is a Float32Array with a length of about 650,000.

The implementation shown above takes between 500 and 800 ms.

The Browser I am using is CefSharp, because the website is run in a C# application.

Is it possible to increase the speed of this code?

Comment: Does this improve any ? `let useVertices = Array(this.indices.length);` and then instead of `useVertices.push(...)` use `useVertices[i] = ...` ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it does by about 200ms

Comment: what about `const useVertices = Array.from(this.indices, (n) => new THREE.Vector3(...this.vertices.slice(n * 3, n * 3 + 3)));` - I doubt it will be any better - but you never know how different JS engines are optimised

Comment: Two other changes, but I don't expect much from either: 1. CefSharp is based on Chromium which uses the V8 JavaScript engine, which will pre-allocate array slots if you use `Array` with a number, so: `let useVertices = Array(len);` (moving it after the `const len =` line). That may help avoid re-allocations. 2. Use `const useVertices` instead of `let` if you don't need to reassign it, in the (probably vain) hope V8 will know it can more aggressively cache the address of the array.

Comment: Unless your vertex triplets overlap, I suspect you can ignore `this.indices`. Instead, iterate `i` over the length of `this.vertices`, step by 3, and use `i` as the index. Then you can drop the `index` variable, removing the multiplication.

Comment: @JaromandaX this javacript engine increases the time that takes by a factor of 3

Comment: yeah, I didn't think that code would help ... cool code though :p

Comment: Okay, another **very** micro-opt: `const V = THREE.Vector3; const { indices, vertices} = this;` and then use `new V` instead of `new THREE.Vector3`, `indices` instead of `this.indices`, and `vertices` instead of `this.vertices`. This avoids unnecessary property lookups in the loop.

Comment: Do you really need to create 4 million `Vector3` objects at all? The best optimisation is to not do any looping at all. Pass the typed arrays directly to the shaders.

Comment: Given the sizes of your arrays, it seems like there are more indices than points which means that, the way you're converting them to objects, you create multiple objects for the same point. Is that the intent?

Comment: Re @Ouroborus's point, it would be interesting to see if reusing objects helps. You could use a `Map` (`const vectors = new Map();`) and use the vertices as keys (```const v0 = vertices[index]; const v1 = vertices[index + 1]; const v2 = vertices[index + 2]; const key = `${v0}_${v1}_${v2}`;```) Then `let vector = vectors.get(key); if (!vector) { vector = new V(v0, v1, v2); vectors.set(key, vector); } useVertices[i] = vector;` (Then `vectors.clear();` after the loop.) That adds complexity and function calls, while reducing the number of allocated objects. So hard to say what it would do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Constructing the key like that seems expensive. Could `index` or `indices[i]` be used as the key instead?

Comment: @Ouroborus Doh! Of course we could, because the vertices are derived from that. So that would be much better (I suspect, though, that the biggest cost there would be the calls to `get` and `set`; number-to-string is quite fast. But not having to do it is even faster. :-) ) Using `index` would also open up the possibility of using a sparse array or an object instead of a `Map`, avoiding function calls. (If an array, only if the values are all under 2**32 - 2: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#array-index)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This code is extremely fast. Using the first approach with the string makes it run in about 250ms and using the index reduces it to about 50ms. If you post this as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: @Plat00n - LOL, I was literally writing that as you commented. :D I've updated the existing answer, very much a community effort. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gathering together what I *think* are the best suggestions from the comments (other than frame challenges) pending your testing them:

- [Ouroborus pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77664957/fast-way-to-fill-array-with-objects/77665098?noredirect=1#comment136921109_77664957) that since you have 4M indices but only 650k vertices, you'll often be creating equivalent `THREE.Vector3` instances. We can reuse instances instead, remembering previous ones based on `index`.
- [Gabriele Petrioli pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77664957/fast-way-to-fill-array-with-objects#comment136920876_77664957) that you can use assignment rather than `push`, saving a method call: `useVertices[i] = ___`
- You can pre-allocate the array using `new Array(len)`
- Avoid unnecessary property lookups by caching `indices`, `vertices`, and `THREE.Vector3`
- Use `const` for `useVertices` if you can

```
const { indices, vertices } = this;
const V = THREE.Vector3;
const len = indices.length;
const useVertices = new Array(len);
const vectors = new Map(); // For reusing vectors
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let index = indices[i] * 3;
    let vector = vectors.get(index);
    if (!vector) {
        vector = new V(
            vertices[index],
            vertices[index + 1],
            vertices[index + 2]
        );
        vectors.set(index, vector);
    }
    useVertices[i] = vector;
}
```

(Note: Plat00n tried using an array instead of a `Map` above, but even with the `get` and `set` method calls, the `Map` was faster.)

Comment: Tank you for combining the different comments. This code is more stable in the execution time. My code fluctuates between 500 and 800ms, this code between 450 and 650

Comment: @Plat00n - Your edit makes `vectors` a `Map`, but then the code uses `vectors[index]` to access elements. That isn't how `Map`s work, did you mean to use `get` and `set`? Or is that really the code you tested? (If so, `vectors` could just be `{}` [or `[]` if the `index` assumption is valid].)

Comment: It works in my code and runs faster

Comment: @Plat00n - Yes, it will *work*, but it's somewhat misleading because it's using a `Map` as though it were a plain object, not as a `Map`. That is, it's not using `Map`'s features. I suggest replacing `= new Map()` with `= []` and seeing how that works (will `index` always be < 2**32 - 2 [4,294,967,294]?).

Comment: I just tested it with using the Map, this time correctly, and it is about twice as fast as using the array.

Comment: @Plat00n - Really?? Wow, that's surprising. Okay, I'll do a further edit to show that. (I'm really surprised by that, but it goes to show that you really can't make assumptions...)

Comment: @Plat00n - Done. :-) Does that look right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use - Vectorized approach

- Use typed arrays (Float32Array) directly for useVertices instead of pushing elements individually.
- Use vectorized operations like slice and copy to manipulate these typed arrays instead of looping through individual elements.
- Leverage vectorized functions provided by Three.js like Vector3.fromArray to directly convert from the vertices array to useVertices.

  ```
   // Allocate typed array directly
   const useVertices = new Float32Array(this.indices.length * 3);

   // Loop through indices and copy data
   for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < this.indices.length; i++, j += 3) {
     const index = this.indices[i] * 3;
     useVertices.copyWithin(j, this.vertices, index, index + 3);
   }

   // Alternatively, use Vector3.fromArray  
   const useVertices = THREE.Vector3.fromArray(this.vertices, 
   this.indices);
  ```